# Generate editable data grids for existing database (Lightswitch alternative)

Tags: software-development, database, code-generation

We have an existing database that we need an editing UI for. For 70% of the tables we just need a simple editable data grid. The other 30% have one-to-many relationships that require a more sophisticated view, so the app builder must either support that or produce customizable code.  If the database schema changes, we need to be to easily update/regenerate the app to reflect the changes.

Ideally, it would be self-hosted rather than cloud-based, so it can access internal databases without going through a firewall.

Lightswitch did this brilliantly. I've spent a week evaluating other options and am coming up short. Radzen seems like it could maybe do it, but their trial (Community Edition) has this feature disabled.

There are a few similar questions, but they don't address the core requirement that it must be easy to generate CRUD view (preferable inline-editable data grids, for editing speed) from an existing database and easily update the app when the database changes.

Comment: what type of database (sql)?

Comment: Microsoft  SQL Server